# How to setup Exchange server mail and address book accounts on OS X Snow Lepord?

Tags: macos, gmail, exchange, apple-mail

I want setup my 3 mail accounts (1x Gmail, 1x Hotmail, and 1x Corporate using Google Apps) on my Mac, but I want them to work the way they work on my iPhone and my iPad, using Exchange.

It really makes life easy to be able to receive and respond to mail instantly, not to mention the contact and calendar syncing.

Any ideas? I have found the 'Exchange 2007' and 'Exchange IMAP' options when setting up the account, but things like the server address and all?

Comment: Do you know what version of Exchange your server is running?

Comment: Ummm... I would like to think that since I'm trying to get my Gmail and Hotmail accounts working, this should be public knowledge? (Sadly, I am unware of it, hence the question)

Comment: Pardon me, my question was crazy. Gmail and Google Apps mail are the same and hotmail's not a big deal either.. I'll give an actual answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exchange option you are looking for requires you know the internal and external servers for google exchange (the m.google.com you use on iPhone does not work)... I have been trying for a while to find this exchange server path.

So meantime looks like manual... if you find POST.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that m.google.com wouldn't work... Someone mentioned that Google supports ActiveSync (or something along those lines) which only permits exchange like behavior for mobile clients...

Answer (score 1):

For Microsoft Outlook 2011 on OS X I use Exchange for Gmail.

Tell Outlook to configure automatically. When that fails, the server name window will show up. Put in `mail.google.com` and save. Close the preference pane and click "Send/Receive" and the mail will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's an answer involving configuring the "mail" app in OSX to be able to use those 3 mail services. You mentioned using exchange, but we're going to need a lot more information as to how exchange applies in this case, as you're talking about 3 non-exchange options, it would seem,

I suggest you start by configuring "POP" access to your gmail accounts. In the gmail/google apps cases, you have to enable this setting for your account. There's a mail settings link in the upper right-hand corner of your browser screen for gmail - go in there and enable pop access. This guide has [steps for configuring "mail" to work with gmail](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20041110192454841). [This one is the same, but for hotmail](http://email.about.com/od/macosxmailtips/qt/How_to_Access_Windows_Live_Hotmail_with_Mac_OS_X_Mail.htm).

Note that when setting up your google apps account follow the same steps as you did for gmail, but note, of course, your domain will be something custom, not gmail.com.

As for your contacts, a bit of googling has shown me you can export your hotmail contacts to file and import that in to "Address Book" - but I don't think that's what you really want.

Since you apparently have an iphone, you can [sync your gmail contacts with the OSX Address Book](http://lifehacker.com/393810/mac-os-xs-address-book-can-now-sync-google-contacts-update-for-iphone-owners-only-ugh).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I already know POP and IMAP configurations, as I've done them before... But I have all three mail accounts configured under Exchange on my iPhone and my iPad... I just can't seem to get them to work on the mail app... I've even tried Microsoft Outlook for Mac 2011... :-(

Comment: I'm confused by this question.. If they're the services you described, then I'm unsure what they'd have to do with exchange??

Comment: Hey there, I got to know that there's something along the lines of 'ActiveSync', which only works for mobile devices, apparently... And Google doesn't do the same thing for desktop applications... talk about walking into a dead end...